# Unable to start debugging on bash on Windows within Visual Studio Code

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging, gdbserver

I have installed WSL(Ubuntu on Windows) and gcc/gdb, and open a directory in Visual Studio Code, then click Debug Menu | add configuration, select C/C++:(gdb) Bash on
 Windows launch, press F5，get the message:

Unable to start debugging, Unable to establish a connection to GDB, ...

output in debug console:

Starting: "C:\Windows\sysnative\bash.exe" "/usr/bin/gdb --interpreter=mi"

"C:\Windows\sysnative\bash.exe" exited with code -1 (0xFFFFFFFF).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough points to leave a comment, but could you paste your 
configuration in `launch.json`? One issue I have seen is that `"/usr/bin/gdb --interpreter=mi"` gets treated as single string instead of calling `gdb` with an extra flag. Updating my configuration with the following flag in `pipeArgs` fixed the error for me.

```js
"configurations": [
  ...,
  "pipeTransport": {
    "debuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
    ...
    "pipeArgs"; ["-c"],
  }
]
```